# How to find indices for matching values in data.frame in R

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Let's say I have

```
dat <- as.data.frame(matrix(LETTERS, 10, 5), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

and I want to replace the elements that matches with the elements in the following character vector with `vowel`

```
vowels <- c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
```

the following doesn't work

```
dat[dat %in% vowels] <- "vowel"
```

it works if I convert the `dat` to matrix but it is not feasible with my real data because of its size and memory issues.

How do I go about doing it in base and tidyverse or data.table? Plus points for if I can fit in multiple matching conditions, such as if I have another vector to match against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%in%` works with `vector`s/matrices.  According to `?"%in%"`

> x - vector or NULL: the values to be matched. Long vectors are supported.
>
> table -vector or NULL: the values to be matched against. Long vectors are not supported.

and not on `data.frame`

```
dat[] <- lapply(dat, function(x) replace(x, x %in%vowels, "vowel"))
dat
#      V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
#1  vowel     K vowel vowel vowel
#2      B     L     V     F     P
#3      C     M     W     G     Q
#4      D     N     X     H     R
#5  vowel vowel     Y vowel     S
#6      F     P     Z     J     T
#7      G     Q vowel     K vowel
#8      H     R     B     L     V
#9  vowel     S     C     M     W
#10     J     T     D     N     X
```

---

With `tidyverse`, we can use `mutate_all`

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>%
        mutate_all(~ replace(., . %in% vowels, 'vowel'))
```

In the newer version of `dplyr`, we can use `across` with `mutate`

```
dat <- dat %>%
          mutate(across(everything(), ~ replace(., . %in% vowels, 'vowel')))
```

If there are multiple sets to compare, either use `case_when` or `ifelse`

```
dat %>%
     mutate_all(~ case_when(. %in% vowels ~ 'vowel', . %in% secondset ~ 'newval', . %in% thirdset ~ 'others'))
```

---

With `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(dat)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) replace(x, x %in% vowels, 'vowel'))]
```

Comment: This is really nice. Thank you for presenting multiple ways to do this. Another quick question, in `mutate_all` is it possible to use the name of a respective column, on which the operation is done, inside the function for comparison? For instance if I want to do `mutate_all(~ replace(., . == colname(.), 'vowel'))`

Comment: in other words, is there a way to get the name of the column being processed inside the `mutate_all`?

Comment: @cropgen In the previous release, it was possible with `funs(~ deparse(subsitute(.)))`, now that is not possible,  You can use `imap(~ replace(.x, .x == .y, 'vowel'))`